# O Linq gera este ID? Como recuperar?

Tags: c#, linq, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo um automatização usando o Selenium WebDriver e estou pegando todos os elementos  de uma Table.

Usei o código abaixo:

```
var qntd= driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='dataTable']/tbody/tr")).Skip(3);
```

Percebi então que cada elemento gerou um Id que não é do atributo Id do Html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei recuperar este id com uma query mas não consegui, pois o retorno é o Atributo Id do HTML

```
var query = from a in qntd
                    select a.GetAttribute("Id");
```

De onde vem este ID e como recupera-lo?

Comment: Voce quer retornar um elemento pelo id? Se sim talvez este código pode te ajudar driver.FindElement(By.Id("ID"));

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente você não poderei acessar este campo porque o método "FindElements" retorna os elementos na forma do IWebElement. O IWebElement não possui um método implementado para obter o valor ID que estava procurando.

Se o método FindElements fosse retornar o tipo RemoteWebElement, ou mesmo o ChromeWebElement, poderíamos acessar esse campo porque o RemoteWebElement possui um método para acessá-lo. No entanto, esse método não é implementado na interface. Portanto, não há como conseguir isso. Então, não estou vendo uma maneira de obter essa ID.

Consulte o código-fonte RemoteWebElement.cs para obter mais informações:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebElement.cs